# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to

Tags: angularjs

I am trying this angular app for first time. I did a setup as per webstorm and bower components and installed angularjs packages in webstorm

My AngularJS App
      
      
    
      -->
      
     </script>-->
    
    
    
    
      myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

```
</script>
<body>


  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>
  <!-- actual angular code bloack in div -->
  <div id="main" ng-app = "app">
    <nav class = "{{active}}" ng-click="$event.preventDefault">
      <a href="#" class ="home" ng-click="active='home'">Home</a>
      <a href="#" class = "projects" ng-click="active='projects">Projects</a>
      <a href="#" class="services" ng-click="active='services'">services</a>
      <a href="#" class="contact" ng-click="active='contact'">Contact</a>

      <p ng-hide="active">Please click a menu item</p>
      <p ng-show="active">you choose<b> {{active}}</b></p>
    </nav>

  </div>



 <!-- <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>-->
 <!-- <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
  <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>-->
</body>`enter code here`
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-app="myapp" should be place in the body or where all the angular meta tags are inside of it, in your case the body, as you see  is currently outside.

Also in ng-app you should put exactly the same name that you put in the declaration of the module.

```
angular.module([MODULE_NAME], []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your HTML like that :

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
```

instead of

```
<div id="main" ng-app = "app">
```

`ng-app` directive must be placed at the top of your site and take the name you've declared in the module. Moreover, if you let `<div ng-view></div>` outside of `ng-app` like you do in your code sample `ng-view` will not work.

Comment: is that answer fits your needs ?